# Stuff and 'For Xml Path' in Sql Server

Tags: xml, t-sql, concatenation

I am using the following code to concatenate all my result into one record (separated by carriage returns)

```
SELECT  [ConcactColumn] =  STUFF((
      SELECT CHAR(10) + t.column 
      FROM #table t
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
      )
```

The only issue is I am not able to have a result with more than 43,720 characters when I need to fit at least 5,000,000 .

how can I achieve this ? thank you in advance.

Comment: 5,000,000 is a steep ask for this.  Curious what the intent is? Maybe there is a better way to resolve the issue.  Another thought is try output to text -- CTRL+T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a string in SSMS is limited. But the Size of an XML is not

- right click into query window
- options
- Results in grid
- Set XML to "umlimited"

Then try this:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (
      SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + t.name
      FROM sys.objects t
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FOR XML PATH('');
```

I cut away 2 characters with `STUFF()` due to `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`. With `CHAR(10)` only you must change this to `...),1,1,'')`.

If the first line might stay blank you can go without `STUFF`

```
SELECT
    (
      SELECT CHAR(10) + t.name
      FROM sys.objects t
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FOR XML PATH('');
```

Click the XML and you see a result which is limited by your machines capacity only...

Comment: Thanks, I knew that one could set the size limit, but I got distracted and never found my way back.  We can always count on you

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to copy from the results grid, take a peek here http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/951995/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode

Perhaps this can help

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = ''
Select @S = @S + char(10) +  t.column 
 From  #table t
 Where t.column  is not null

Select Len(@S)

SELECT  [ConcactColumn] = @S
```

Comment: it is taking it as a command and not really producing any result.
     Command(s) completed successfully.

Comment: This would help to get a very long string, but how would you get your hands on it? `PRINT` will cut this, `SELECT` will cut it too... I just placed an answer how to solve this *within* the XML result view, which is not limited in size...

Answer (score 1):

This used to give me fits. I love this stored procedure and, although I wish I wrote it, I didn't (credit in the comments).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LongPrint @string nvarchar(MAX)
AS
/* 
Source:
https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/3102/any-way-around-the-print-limit-of-nvarcharmax-in-s.html

Example:
exec LongPrint @string = 'This String Exists to test the system.'

This procedure is designed to overcome the limitation in the SQL print command that causes 
it to truncate strings longer than 8000 characters (4000 for nvarchar).

It will print the text passed to it in substrings smaller than 4000 characters. If there 
are carriage returns (CRs) or new lines (NLs in the text), it will break up the substrings
at the carriage returns and the printed version will exactly reflect the string passed.

If there are insufficient line breaks in the text, it will print it out in blocks of 4000 
characters with an extra carriage return at that point.
If it is passed a null value, it will do virtually nothing.

NOTE: This is substantially slower than a simple print, so should only be used when actually needed. */

DECLARE 
  @CurrentEnd bigint, /* track the length of the next substring */
  @offset tinyint     /*tracks the amount of offset needed */

set @string = replace(replace(@string, char(13)+char(10), char(10)), char(13), char(10));

WHILE LEN(@String) > 1 BEGIN
  IF CHARINDEX(char(10), @string) BETWEEN 1 AND 4000
  BEGIN 
    SET @CurrentEnd = CHARINDEX(char(10), @String) -1;
    SET @offset     = 2;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @CurrentEnd = 4000;
    SET @offset     = 1;
  END;

  PRINT SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @CurrentEnd);

  SET @string = SUBSTRING(@String, @CurrentEnd+@offset, 1073741822);

END /*End While loop*/
```

You would use the proc like this:

```
DECLARE @results varchar(max);

SELECT @results =  STUFF((
      SELECT CHAR(10) + t.column 
      FROM #table t
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

EXEC dbo.LongPrint @results;
```

So we're clear: *This solution is **not** designed for blazing fastness.*

Comment: This code was written 2009... Those days it was great, but nowadays you can use the unlimited output to XML...